# integrating django with aiohttp/asyncio

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to integate django with aiohttp/asyncio
for asynchronous programming and for websockets handling.
I know django has celery & django-channels to do asynchronous task  and websocket server respectively but aiohttp is having both asynchronous and websocket server pre built  in it and I found that framework more scalable and easy, compared to celery/django channels while creating a function to webscraping (I don't know if webscraping can be possible in celery I, havent tried it yet).
And it also supports async and await perfectly.

But my question is: How can we implement both django and aiohttp in a project? Instead using django's development server can we use aiohttp server to serve the site.

And are we able to integrate django with aiohttp function (like lets take an example: If I want to scrape a website of user submmited input to my database. Can I use await calls in my function while fetching the website and posting the following website to my django database?  Or post the function results to another django function?)

And I want to know the disadvantages of integrating, if any?

And while posting  your answer please could you post a sample practical example of integration instead suggesting  me those libraries over github.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is time for considering Django >= 4.1 wich already have built-in [Asynchronous Support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/#asynchronous-support)

From the docs:

> Django has support for writing asynchronous (“async”) views, along with an entirely async-enabled request stack if you are running under ASGI. Async views will still work under WSGI, but with performance penalties, and without the ability to have efficient long-running requests.

> We’re still working on async support for the ORM and other parts of Django. You can expect to see this in future releases. For now, you can use the sync_to_async() adapter to interact with the sync parts of Django. There is also a whole range of async-native Python libraries that you can integrate with.